# Get selected text from a select in Magento mail template?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, email-templates

lets say I have a select box (dropdown) that is called *test*. I can get the selected value in my mail using

```
{{var data.test}} --> gives me 2 for example
```

How can I get the text that was selected, not the value. I already tried:

```
{{var data.test.text}}
```

This makes no difference, I still get 2. Ideas?

Thanks!